# CoreBluetooth only support Bluetooth 4.0?

Tags: ipad, bluetooth

CoreBluetooth only support Bluetooth 4.0?

Using CoreBlutooth, I can not find my iPod3 from Mac Mini. Who can tell me if can i develop Bluetooth program on the old apple device（like iPod3）?

```
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]] options:options];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the [framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf) reference:

> The CoreBluetooth framework provides access to Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices.

So yes, the CoreBluetooth only works with iPhone 4S's and new iPad's.

To develop using Bluetooth to your older devices, use [IOBluetoothUserLib](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothUserLib_h/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

also remember that discovery of Bluetooth LE devices is only available in app, ie you cannot find LE devices through the standard iOS Bluetooth settings, you have to write an app for it.